# Would questions about finding images that fit a description on-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, on-topic

I have an idea and would like to find an image that well illustrates it. It isn't mentioned explicitly in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Below is my sample question:

> I am looking for images to illustrate an idea (or photographers that may produce image like that). I imagine the image would be a person giving us an impression that they are **observing us carefully**. Their look would be direct at us. However it doesn't feel like they are about to do any harm. Just a neutral observation on us. Some people may feel it's cold or detached.
>
> I find [this image in Unsplash](https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516496020833-94df152243ae?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&dl=sergei-gavrilov-azRT6wDcLqM-unsplash.jpg) whose eye depiction really fits what I'm looking for, but lying may not best describe the feeling of being observed carefully. I'm looking for other position, perhaps sitting or standing.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This site is mostly dedicated to talking about how to create images, rather than how to find existing images. A question that would be on topic might be something like, "How do I create an image that illustrates an idea?" Another would be, "How do I create a photo like this example?"

Questions about how to locate images that are not historically significant to the science or art of photography, or that are not about otherwise iconic photos because they are images of historically significant events or persons, have been routinely closed here in the past.

When we do talk about existing images, they tend to be images that were historically significant in the development of the science and art of photography.

Comment: How about asking this? "What are efficient ways to locate images that fit a description?"

Comment: You're still asking about *finding* images, rather than *making* images. This community is about the *practice of photography*. It's not about locating photographs.

Comment: I know, but it's about the method to find any image, not to find a specific image. It's like teaching how to fish rather just giving the fish. The process of making anything including learning from similar products (standing on giant's shoulders), and this requires the skills to find them first. See also: [Questions about (famous) photographers](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/165/70665)

Comment: There's still a big difference between looking for images that are considered historically significant to the development and history of the science and art of photography and looking for images that fit an intended usage. Please also consider that this community has evolved significantly from when it was almost brand new in 2010 and that question was asked/answered. We have lots of good questions about historically significant photographs or movements and the photographers that made them. We've almost always closed questions about "How can I find a photo of..."

Comment: so it seems like you need to have a specific image and ask about stuff around it? How about asking about images that are significant in philosophical movements in photography? Also, do you know any meta discussion about questions about "How can I find a photo of..."?

Comment: We have a number of questions about images created by the leaders of various philosophical movements in photography. For example: [Why are the Becher typologies considered artistically valuable?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/101579/15871) and [Why is “The Steerage” hailed “one of the greatest photographs of all time”?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/104365/15871) and [What was the Group f.64, and why were they important?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/101476/15871) and [Why did “pure” photography displace pictorialism so completely?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/37616/15871)

Comment: Also: [Who were the Bauhaus photographers and what was their impact on commercial and artistic photography today?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/106056/15871) and [What was Bob Parent's “Signature Technique,” and how is it visible in this (linked) photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/105877/15871)

Comment: Here's a question and answer that are pretty much the flip side of what you seem to want to ask. [Which photography movements do these images fit?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/114338/15871)